# ¿Como mandar un arreglo a un web services en angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, webservice

Hola Estoy consumiendo los datos de un web services con JSON y el problema es que estoy haciendo 2 veces la misma petición porque id_servicio contiene dos numero en un arreglo( 38 y 39 ) y estos me devuelven datos distintos. (son sucursales distintas) por ahora estoy mandando id_servicio de la siguiente manera:

peticion 1:

```
      $scope.DateNormal = Ticket.getAll({

    id_usuario: LoginData.getData().id_usuario,
    token: LoginData.getData().token,
    id_sucursal: LoginData.getData().id_sucursal,
    id_servicio: LoginData.getData().id_servicio.split(",")[0],
```

peticion 2:

```
      $scope.DatePriority = Ticket.getAll({

    id_usuario: LoginData.getData().id_usuario,
    token: LoginData.getData().token,
    id_sucursal: LoginData.getData().id_sucursal,
    id_servicio: LoginData.getData().id_servicio.split(",")[1],
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿puedo mandar los dos de uno? ¿como?.

Datos:

- Me responde con los datos en JSON
- LoginData.getdata()  corresponde a otros datos recibidos en JSON desde un web services y que se guardaron en esta variable.

Saludos.

Comment: pero no usas json para enviar los datos ? ademas no entiendo si los envias o los recuperas ya que el split() que muestras parece que lo implementas en javascript ya que usas un getData(), el webservice en que tecnologia esta creado?

Comment: lo explicare en el documeno

Comment: No se entiende mucho tu pregunta. Creo que debes poner el código relevante y poner un ejemplo de los datos. De lo contrario es imposible responderte.

Comment: en que documento ?

Comment: modifique el documento

Answer (score 1):

Si el servicio Ticket.getAll recibe un array de id_servicio, sí.
Lo podrías hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
$scope.DateNormal = Ticket.getAll({
    id_usuario: LoginData.getData().id_usuario,
    token: LoginData.getData().token,
    id_sucursal: LoginData.getData().id_sucursal,
    id_servicio: LoginData.getData().id_servicio
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No se entiende bien tu pregunta pero espero que sea esta la respuesta.
No es necesario hacer 2 peticiones, puedes enviar los 2 números como un array o como una cadena. pero para eso tendrias que modificar tu servicio y permita aceptar n ids ya sea en array o en cadena.

```
var Dates = Ticket.getAll({
    id_usuario: LoginData.getData().id_usuario,
    token: LoginData.getData().token,
    id_sucursal: LoginData.getData().id_sucursal,
    //opciones dependiendo de que te devuelva LoginData.getData().id_servicio
    id_servicio: LoginData.getData().id_servicio  // <-- [38,39] 
    id_servicio: LoginData.getData().id_servicio.join(",") // [38,39] --> "38,39"
    id_servicio: LoginData.getData().id_servicio.split(",") // "38,39" --> [38,39]
});
$scope.DateNormal = Dates[0];  
$scope.DatePriority = Dates[1];
```

Si no quieres modificar tu servicio en todo caso caballero tendrías que hacer 2 peticiones

Answer (score 0):

> Mi pregunta es: ¿puedo mandar los dos de uno? ¿como?.

Tu pregunta no tiene que ver con como tratar los JSON desde AngularJS, si no, de tu funcion en el WS que pueda recibir 1 o más parametros, en este caso de id_servicio y devolver los datos esperados para cada uno.

Y la respuesta es : SI, configura tu WS para que sea capaz de recibir un arreglo de ID o de Objectos tipo servicio para poder 1 por 1 iterando y haciendo lo que necesitas. En estos momentos la funcion de tu WS debe estar esperando :

```
Ticket.getAll({
    id_usuario: LoginData.getData().id_usuario,
    token: LoginData.getData().token,
    id_sucursal: LoginData.getData().id_sucursal,
    id_servicio: LoginData.getData().id_servicio.split(",")[0]
})
```

Si quieres enviar 2 o más debes prepararlo para que pueda recibir distintos objetos con esta misma estructura.

Saludos!